# how to open or read copied system registry file without import in windows 10

Tags: windows, powershell, registry

I have copied **system** registry file **C:\Windows\system32\config\system** from another windows machine (VM). And I want to open it and list out some keys from "...\ControlSet.." I open the Regedit and tried to open it but Regedit showing me the option of import which giving the warning that the registry keys ill be get replaced.

So I want to open it with PowerShell if not possible then want some tool to open the file and list out the required keys from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your PowerShell script, you can use reg load/unload to automate what you described above.

```
$null = reg load HKU\CustomFolderName "c:\path\SYSTEM.DAT"
...
script code here
...
$null = reg unload HKU\CustomFolderName
```

Answer (score 0):

Found one way is using Load Hive Option in Regedit.

Select the Hive **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE** or **HKEY_USERS** then
  *'File > Load Hive'* then select the file to load then
  Write the path or name of the key in the opened dialog box.
  If the key does not exist in the selected hive it will create key and will load the 
selected file under it.